# Default charset on every pare including error pages

Tags: apache-2.4, custom-errors, charset

I would like to produce a 404 error intentionally for some pages on my server, and I am currently working on the headers. The problem is, for the scripts that exists (and I give a 404 error in the script), the `Content-Type` header field shows `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, while for the real 404 pages the same field shows `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, which defeats my purpose. I've tried adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the main config but there's no luck. The question is, how to set the charset on these real error pages?

Comment: Define "I give a 404 error in the script"? Is that Apache server returning a 404? some other backend?

Comment: It's something like `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')`

Comment: so it's your script making the response , make your script return the correct charset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: Use `ErrorDocument` for the desired error code (in this case 404), make it point to a script under the web root, then setting whatever I like in the `ErrorDocument`.